# Get SalesChannelProuctRepository in custom entity association

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have created a custom entity. It has a connection with the `ProductDefinition`. Now, I want that I need `SaleChannelProductEntity` in the Product association.

How can I get the `SalesChannelProductEntity` association(ManyToOne)?

I tried with the `Product` association, but it's getting ProductEntity as the association is added with the `ProductDefinition`.

Comment: I have not tried it, but have you tried to use `SalesChannelProductDefinition` instead of the `ProductDefinition`?

Comment: @newgennerd Yes, tried with that, but not getting/getting null the `SalesChannelProductRepository` fields as the context will be passed as normal `Context` instead of `SalesChannelContext`.

Comment: Okay then I see no other possibility to do this then loading the `SaleChannelProductEntity` again using the `SalesChannelProductRepository` at the place where you have the saleschannel-context using the `id` you get from the product association... But maybe someone else has a better idea :)

Comment: @newgennerd Thank you for the suggestion, but I cannot use that as I need to implement it in the loop if something goes wrong then it'll not be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just extend your regular definition and implement the `SalesChannelDefinitionInterface`. Just have a look at the [`SalesChannelCategoryDefinition`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/d1d52735823eecf999cfeffd538731c7ae4dcc3b/src/Core/Content/Category/SalesChannel/SalesChannelCategoryDefinition.php) for reference. Then you register the sales channel definition additionally:

```xml
<service id="My\Plugin\Definition\SalesChannelCustomEntityDefinition">
    <tag name="shopware.sales_channel.entity.definition"/>
</service>
```

You can then inject the sales channel repository of your custom entity like so: `sales_channel.custom_entity.repository`. If you use that repository, associations to `ProductDefinition` should then yield instances of `SalesChannelProductEntity` instead.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something like you said. Now I got the full idea. Thank you!